# Magento : How to stop register process for spam/junk customer?

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, registration

I'm facing a problem, junk/fake customer are registering on Magento. I would like to know if someone has experienced same and how it can be fixed.

I'm not found of using captcha solutions, I would rather intercept customer profil before regestering, write some rules on names, email etc... but i'did not managed to stop process.

so I write an observer based on event "customer_save_before"
and i'm able to detect when it's a fake one, but i'm unable to stop registering proccess.

code looks summarized like

```
    $event              = $observer->getEvent();
    $customer           = $event->getCustomer();
```

after some logic to detect junk, I don't be able to have some action on this customer.

maybe i'm too late in magento process to stop it ? More probably, this is because 'im using an observer and it cannot really stop other running task, like registering...

any help appreciated,

Regards,

Comment: Used Recaptcha validation

Comment: Thanks @jigsparmar but i'm actually looking for a way of doing this without captcha, as mentionned.

Comment: use form key validation

Comment: Tried this? https://magecomp.com/magento-new-recaptcha.html

Answer (score 2):

You can enable a Magento Captcha for a register form in `System > Configuration > Customers > Customer Cunfiguration > Captcha`, you can use also a [Google recaptcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/invisible.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, captcha is not the best solution for protecting your website from spam.  It irritates users, makes them leave your website, and is unsafe.  You’d better try cleantalk. They have created algorithms to ensure reliability and accuracy against spam bots. It will save your time and resources, allowing you to focus on developing and improving your website. Cleantalk provides logs of all the processed requests that allows you to check results of spam filters. Security log includes IP/country/data/time, username and action result, was authorization successful or failed. Regular analysis of parameters allows you to find new spam patterns of behavior.